# CSS: li wont center inside a ul

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a list inside a ul but it won't work. What's wrong? I used used text center but it still won't work.

```css
.mainNav {
  background-color: #B00002;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 204px;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 33px;
  padding-right: 37px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="mainNav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove padding from `ul`.

```css
.mainNav {
  background-color: #B00002;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 204px;
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0; /* HERE */
}

li {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 33px;
  padding-right: 37px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="mainNav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `ul` padding to 0. By default it sets to 40px.

```css
.mainNav {
background-color: #B00002;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
list-style-type: none;
width: 204px;
margin-top: auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
}
li {
text-align: center;
}
a {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 33px;
padding-right: 37px;
padding-left: 37px;
text-decoration: none;
```

```html
 <ul class="mainNav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">History</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove text-align from `li` and `.mainNav`

```css
.mainNav {
  background-color: #B00002;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 204px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

li {
}

a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 33px;
  padding-right: 37px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="mainNav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```